# Jquery autocomplete getting id cha

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I made this code with jquery autocomplete its just like facebook search function now the problem is i am getting userid and i am storing it in textfield hidden but if some user presses backspace the id remains same of old user that was searched before as i am storing id on select .. plust i want to restrict the user not to go ahead other than selecing any user from database ..
here is my code

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#searchbox").autocomplete("search.php", {


    width: 258,
    highlight: false,
    scroll: true,

    scrollHeight: 350,
    dataType: 'json',

    parse: function(data) {
            var array = new Array();
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {

            array[array.length] = { data: data[i], value:           data[i].name, result: data[i].name};

            }
            return array;
    },
    formatItem: function(row) {                     


    var output =  "<img class=img src='user_img/" + row.img + "'/> ";             
    output += "<span class=name>"+row.name+"</span><br/>";
    output += "<span class=small>"+row.country+"</span><br/>";


    return output;
    }




          }).result(function(event,item)
           {


           $('#temp').val(item.uid);


           });
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this method and it worked thanks all for not helping me :(

```
       select: function (event, ui) {
        var v = ui.item.value;
        $('#MessageTo').html("Something here" + v);
        $('#Hidden1').html("Something else here" + v);
        // update what is displayed in the textbox
        this.value = v; 
        return false;
    }
```